What are the best DRY (least repetitive) ways to implement a navbar across all pages of a site?
I want to have a pre-made nav-bar in one .html file and have it linked to several HTML pages, so that I only have to change "nav-bar.html" in order to change what is displayed on all those other pages.
I have achieved this with JavaScript.
(This particular solution works. I have outlined it (and what I don't like about it) in case someone might have wanted to propose/use something similar.)
Explained briefly:
Current solution:

The element '<inserter class="navbar">Home</inserter>', is replaced with the HTML contents of "nav-bar.html". I can copy paste this small element on every page with the same script linked.

Cons of current solution:

This method has one main issue. The un-replaced HTML is rendered first, then the replacement is made, then it re-renders, which leads to a very ugly, brief flash.

What are the better alternatives? e.g.,

Any that use vanilla HTML, CSS, JS? (JQuery is ok too.)
Standard way to do this with PHP.


If you're using PHP then put the navbar code in one file, and include (or require) that file in all the ones where you want it to appear. If you don't want to use PHP, consider Server-Side Includes (if your webserver supports them). Anything you do client-side will inevitably involve some sort of visible delay - e.g. if you load the content via AJAX, or some sort of JS trick, because that must necessarily wait until at least part of the rest of the page has loaded, before starting.

Careful.  You're almost soliciting opinions with the wording of this question.  A better wording of your question might be to either focus on eliminating the flash "How can I eliminate the flash caused by replacing HTML in this way"  (describe a way to reproduce the problem).  Or maybe focus on the DRY requirement:  "How can I declare a navbar on all my pages without repeating this declaration": (be specific and show the code and how it repeats in an undesirable way)"  Avoid wordings that call for "what is the best/better way".  Motivations of "seems janky" are for the code review site.

Depending on what you put in the "nav bar", you might also want to consider a mix of solutions, too. For page-based navigation where you are just setting "active" classes on things, that is still often done server-side. If, however, any part of your navigation also includes user-specific data (the most common examples are the number of items in a shopping cart or log in/out links), you might want to do that client-side for caching reasons.

@Wyck Thank you for the advice. I've edited my question a bit to make it more specific and objective. The focus was intended to be on the DRY aspect, but solutions that do not cause flashes would be preferred.
